# why do some people hate bitfields?

Tags: python, sqlite, bit-manipulation

Is using bitfields has any performance impact?
What are the situations where we should avoid using bitfields/bitwise-operations?

Comment: What is a bitwise "flag", do you mean bitwise operations?

Comment: Are you talking about bitfields? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: Sounds like you might want to rephrase this question's title and get rid of the body, except for the actual two questions. Just a thought.

Comment: this is kindof subjective, and may be closed.  Try programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're using Python and you are concerned about the performance implications of bitwise flags. Time for a reality check. Anyway, why use bitwise flags when you can use sets?

Comment: I like bitwise operations, too. The only downside is that many programmers (and it tends to be the younger ones) simply don't understand them. Personally, I'm fed up with having to answer the question "Should I be using AND or OR?"

Comment: You could say you trade speed for space. A bit is not a lot of data, but you have to do some processing to read it of course. The processing is so pico-minuscule however; it wont matter in any environment that can run Python let alone any Python program :D